# Is there a way ot make a discord bot screen share a website

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm looking for a way to make the bot screen share a website. And the link to be a parameter after the command. (To clarify: The website starting URL doesn't change. Only a token that's given after the starting URL. For example: "https://websitehere.com/branch/ 'token goes here'

Answer (score 2):

Bots Can't Screenshare! Discord Bot API Do Not Support It Yet!

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative with selfbots using JavaScript, You can try this project:

https://github.com/MainSilent/Discord-Screenshare

In order to show a website you need to capture it and show it on the html video element in `stream_inject.js`

Comment: The video is private :/